# modx revo friendly urls

Tags: friendly-url, modx

Just started to use MODX Revo.
When I make new document in MODX(Revo), fill its alias (for example '**TESTALIAS**') and trying to get **mydomain/TESTALIAS** I'm receiving mistake **404**.

Using nginx and php-fpm, FURLs are ON in **.htaccess**

So what am I doing wrong? Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have built the site, browsed around a bit and THEN turned on furls, clear your modx cache. [actually delete all the files]
Also make sure that not only furls are enabled in modx but that:

Use Friendly Alias Path = on

Check for Duplicate URIs Across All Contexts = on

Automatically generate alias = on [not necessary, just handy]

Are you getting the modx 404 error page or the apache 404?

But it sounds like you have not enabled furls in modx system->settings->freindly urls

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that disturbs me is NGINX & .htaccess... htaccess is meant to be used with Apache web server. I guess having a look at http://rtfm.modx.com/display/revolution20/Nginx+Server+Config might be of any use :)

Hope that'll help.

Answer (score 0):

Remember

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
```

Or

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /your-path-from/
```

I've had no problems with friendly URLs in any of my...50 modx-pages over the years.